# mouseenter event is not working in IPad Safari Browser, vesion ios 13.x

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, ios13

We are getting issue in IPad, Safari Browser, suddenly **mouseenter** events is not working after upgraded version to **13.x**

It is working fine with **12.x**

What could be the reason? Is there any bugs related to mouse event in ios 13.x?

What could be the alternative solution to achieve **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** in iPad safari?

Answer (score 0):

don't no why it is not working after upgrade, but you can try using "touchend" event